# Интеграция gitlab c jira

Tags: gitlab, jira, integration-services

Пытаюсь настроить интеграцию jira в gitlab, но ничего не выходит. 
Вношу настройку для подключения к jira , но никакие изменения не попадают в jira. Может надо jira как-то по особенному настраивать? Документация по интеграция https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html#gitlab-jira-integration не помогла. Куда еще можно посмотреть?

[image: Страница интеграции с jira в репозитории]

Answer (score 1):

Web URL должен быть не на jira, a на ссылку компании. [https://**name**.atlassian.net](https://__name__.atlassian.net). Типа того.

Вот есть руководство на хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/451210/